# How to check whether the UITableViewCells are blank

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using indexpathforvisiblerows which gives the indexpaths of the visible rows in uitableview. How can i check for the blank cells in the returned indexpaths?.

` NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.rootViewController.accountTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
    {

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.rootViewController.accountTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // I am getting the issue when i call this function 
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self getLastCallDate:indexPath];


}
```

// getLastCallDate function

Account *account = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *lastCallDate;

```
if ([[account Calls] count] > 0) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

    Call *call = [[account Calls] objectAtIndex:0];

     lastCallDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last Call Date: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:call.date]];

    //NSLog(@"detail - %@", cell.detailTextLabel.text);
    [dateFormatter release];
    return lastCallDate;
}
else
    lastCallDate =@"";
return lastCallDate;
```

`
While searching fetched results controller will not have the values as many as the visible rows which leads to array bound execption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a plain UITableView without section header, just rows. Then the number of rows shown on the display `tableView.frame.size.height / tableView.rowHeight`. Subtract the number of visible rows.

[image: example for empty rows vs. visible cells]

With the above algorithm I get `total rows 16 visible cells 5`.

Now it's up to you to calculate `16 - 5`.

Comment: No i have few tablecells which has data and the rest are blank. I want the count of the cells which has data

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `getLastCallDate:`, check whether `indexPath.row` is less than the number of items in your data source. Something like-

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths) 
{
     if(indexPath.row < [self.items count]) //items is your data source array
     {
          //your code
     }
}
```